# Extend strftime directives to format a time like "tomorrow at 14:00"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, strftime

I've found the list of format directives for the `strftime` method http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime

There are various options to format a time like weekdays, day of month... But I'm interested in formating a Time like

```
Time.parse("2016-02-30T12:24").strftime("%XXX, at %H:%M")
# => tomorrow at 12:24
```

Here `%XXX` should be "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow", "in 2 days" or "in 3 days".

> Is it possible to extend the directives of `strftime` so that I can use my own placeholder?

Comment: Any reason to do it on backend? Don't waste time, use `momentjs`.

Comment: `strftime` doesn't include these, because they are relative to another date / time, e.g. `Time.now`. Furthermore, they depend on the user's timezone, i.e. my "today" doesn't have to be your "today" (although it is in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I think following **distance_of_time_in_words** helper would help.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rails [Distance of Time in Words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) which will give you 'about 1 day' but I think it would be easier to use MomentJS's [Calendar Time](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/).

Calendar Time will help you return something like " Tomorrow at 2:30 AM"

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.